# Upgrading NRF module for drone

Tags: drone

Hello I am trying to make a drone by using Arduino as a microcontroller both for remote controller and the drone. And I have thought for using NRF module. But I came to know it only can transmit data to 1000 m maximum but I need the range around 8 km maximum. What can I do for increasing the range of my drone? Or is there some way to increase range of NRF module?

Comment: This is silly. You won't be able to see the drone that far. How are you going to control what you can't see? You will have to pick transciever that operate at a much lower frequency. Thus limiting the bandwidth. Don't even think about streaming live video on those.

Comment: Most countries have laws about operating drones out of line of site, or over a few hundred meters away, etc. An nRF24L01+ is more than adequate if you want to remain within the law...

Comment: I have managed all the settings there would be ground controlled station only i need to increase maximum range. And I already own drone license.

Answer (score 0):

If I search I see plenty of examples of RF with 40 miles, e.g.:

- [XTend 900 1W RPSMA - 40 Mile Range](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/9411)
- [XBee-900-Datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/Zigbee/XBee-900-Datasheet.pdf)

Possibilities to increase the range:

- More powerful transmitter
- External / better antenna(s)
- Better receiver
- Using directional communication (might be hard with a drone which flies/moves)

Comment: @Juraj ... I meant actually 1000 m, but probably that's his currently used nRF.

Comment: I need a arduino compatible device